# Is it possible to hide mdadm source devices?

Tags: mdadm, block-device

If I set up `mdadm` and I get a `/dev/md*` device, is it possible to hide from plain sight the underlying source devices that make up the array?

I wouldn't want to accidentally write to `/dev/sd*` that is a part of a `mdadm` array.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, but I think impossible to accomplish, I'm afraid.

Sadly, no, it is not possible.